# How to receive DataTables selected rows IDs (DT_RowId) through a form

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I have set up DataTables server-side and I have inserted the rows multiple selection just like their example page here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html

My script is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form').submit( function() {
   alert( "Response: \n\n"+selected );
   } );

$('#count').click( function () {
    alert( selected.length +' row(s) selected' );
} );


var selected = [];

var MyTable = $("#DT_Table").dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "dt_proc/dtp_clients.inc.php",
    "dom": '<"top"ifp>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
        if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
            $(row).addClass('selected');
        }
    }

});

$('#DT_Table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

    var id = this.id;
    var index = $.inArray(id, selected);

    if ( index === -1 ) {
        selected.push( id );
    } else {
        selected.splice( index, 1 );
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

} );
```

} );

So I can now select the rows, and var selected = []; has the values I need (the clients IDs)

Now, I have added a form with button to delete selected rows, and I when I press the button, I expect to receive those ID's through POST so I can process them, but I can't figure out how.

The HTML is this:

```
<form method="post" id="form">
  <input type="submit" name="go" value="Show!" id="submit"/>
  <input type="button" name="go" value="COUNT!" id="count"/>
  <table id="DT_Table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Client title</th>
        <th>Store</th>
        <th>Date added</th>
        <th>Campaign</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Expires</th>
        <th>Clicks</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Client title</th>
        <th>Store</th>
        <th>Date added</th>
        <th>Campaign</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Expires</th>
        <th>Clicks</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="pag" value="list_clients" />
</form>
```

The function below shows me the selected ID's (i.e. row_3640,row_2861,row_3876)

```
   $('#form').submit( function() {
    alert( "Selected rows IDs: \n\n"+selected );
} );
```

And the Count button also works..
but its quite frustrating that I don't know how to get them known by the PHP.
Thank you very much for any clues...

Comment: Define an form action in HTML `action="yourform.php"`, then retrieve the values in the PHP file (`$_POST`)

Comment: The form includes the DataTable. it is specified method="post" but no action file because I want to process the form in the same file after submit. When button is submitted, I parse the POST vars that comes, but no selected, or DT_Row_IDs or anything like that

Comment: Then do you have the relevant PHP in the same file (to grab the `$_POST` value and process it)?

Comment: `foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
     $message.= $key . ' has the value of <strong>' . $value."</strong><br>";
 }`   - no var is coming out through POST

Comment: Does `$_REQUEST` actually contain anything? Try `var_dump($_REQUEST)`. If it doesn't, then check if you set the name attribute for your HTML inputs.

Comment: this is what var_dump shows:  ***array(4) { ["pag"]=> string(12) "list_clients" ["go"]=> string(5) "What?" ["DT_Table_length"]=> string(2) "25" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "114e0c8a9a49fede89f22e324aac70ea" } ***          -- As you can see, nothing relevant.. I wonder there my selected rows are...

Comment: Clearly, nothing's been posted. Did you follow the ajax example in the DataTables API? Or do you have your own HTML form solution? Whatever the case it'll probably help if you post the relevant jQuery/HTML code here.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code I am using..

Comment: You could try to set the result to a hidden variable in the $('#form').submit( function() { alert( "Selected rows IDs: \n\n"+selected );  // set hidden variable value here  });

Comment: Thank you very much Stamen! i added a hidden HTML var: `<input type="hidden" name="selected" value="" />`   and I added into that function:  `$('input[name=selected]').val(selected);`   and worked like a charm!  regards.

Comment: You are welcome! If you visit this again, you could select the up arrow at the left side of my previous comment to show that it has helped.

Comment: Stamen - I don't have that voting arrow on any comments... I think I do not have the option to vote, my rating may be to low? To avoid pointless commenting here, I tried to send you a message but I couldn't find that option either.

Comment: No worries, I didn't know about these restrictions either. I am also new to this platform. All best and enjoy!